# Shortcuts/Snippets to select a block of code

Tags: ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2016 on Windows 10. I'm tired of using shift/ctrl+up/down/right/left keys to select the code I want to run. I'm wondering whether there are shortcuts/snippets to select a block of code that separated from other code by blank lines?

Here is a code example:

```
select *
from tab1

select *
from tab2

select *
from tab3
```

Say, my cursor is inside the middle block and what's the best way to select the middle block?

Comment: JetBrains DataGrip (Ctrl + Enter). Cheap too. Dark UI too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not affiliated to Red-Gate, but I would like to point out that if you hit Shift-F5, when you own a newish copy of SQL Prompt, then the query your cursor is on, will be marked green, and executed.

It has really saved me a lot of keystrokes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried sql prompty and it was amazing! I'll think about purchasing it after the trial!

Comment: Note that it doesn't actually select the code, inasmuch as you can't use this method to copy the code block that's been executed.

Answer (score 4):

Using Autohotkey, I was able to develop a solution to select a block of code and here is the script I have:

```
!b::

send ^f

sendraw ^\r$

send {F3}

send +{F3}

send {Esc}

send {down}

send ^{=}

return
```

Specifically, pressing Alt + B will invoke this script, and the script will select the block of code where the cursor is in. Note that the block of code has to be separated from other blocks of code by blank lines, and the block of code cannot have blank of lines inside itself.

The key steps of the about script are

- using regular expression "^\r$
  " to locate the blank lines above and below the cursor
- moving the cursor to these two blank lines one by one
- using ctrl + = to select the block of code between these two blank lines.

Note that !/^/+ are alt/ctrl/shift separately.

Comment: I did not know that you could do this with AutoHotKey. A lot less espensive than SQL Prompt. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 4):

One way to quickly select blocks of code within SSMS is to minimize the code using the `-` button next to the leading keyword in a SQL statement  (e.g. SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, WITH, etc.) then highlight that line and press `F5` to execute it.

[image]

Depending on your version of SSMS (newer versions obviously being preferred in this case), there are also some keyboard shortcuts you can use to collapse/expand a section. The [keyboard shortcut link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx#Anchor_7) provided by Simon Hellings' earlier response alludes to hotkeys already being set, but I cannot confirm they actually work.  However, you can set some custom hotkeys to do this as follows:

1. The functions we're concerned with setting hotkeys for are found under the `Edit` -> `Outlining` Menu Options:
   [image]
2. To set the hotkeys, navigate to `Tools` -> `Options...` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard` -> `Keyboard`.  Type in `Outlin` into the ***Show commands containing:*** box.  Then assign a new shortcut key combinations for `Edit.ToggleAllOutlining` and `Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion` and press `Assign`:
   [image]
3. Now, check the shortcuts took after pressing Ok and your shortcut keys should work as expected.  As you can see, I assigned mine to `CTRL+ALT+Left Arrow` and `CTRL+ALT+Right Arrow`, but you can use whatever you want:
   [image]

Finally if this doesn't work, you may have to switch to a different SQL client.  It sounds like the functionality you want is similar to executing an Oracle PL/SQL block via `CTRL + ENTER` within Oracle SQL Developer.  You *can* use Oracle SQL Developer to connect to SQL Server using Third Party Database JDBC drivers ([ref](https://kentgraziano.com/2013/01/14/tech-tip-connect-to-sql-server-using-oracle-sql-developer/)), but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Yes, this alone is reason enough to install [Toad](http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/550) and use F9.  Toad does have its own set of quirks though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How can I fold the tree node without using mouse?

Comment: @Jason - I've updated my answer with the keyboard shortcuts.  You'll need a newer version of SSMS, as this functionality wasn't available on all versions as indicated by the URL link I've provided.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener, thanks for your help and I'll check them out!

Comment: @JohnEisbrener, I was trying to test the new keyboard shortcut you suggested and none of them works for me. I'm using the newest version of SSMS, which is version 13.0.16106.4. Have you ever tested them by yourself?

Comment: @Jason, you're right, they don't work out of the box and in fact they don't work even if you force them.  I updated my answer with a better workaround though which I think will accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener, thanks for your help! I assigned the shortcuts as you suggested and it was really awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `up`/`down`/`right`/`left` keys at all to select your code to run.

Assuming that a computer mouse can be used, do this:

1. Use your computer's mouse to move the cursor to the first character to be included.
2. Next *Hold down and continue holding down* the `Ctrl` key, then move the  mouse to include the last character to be included.
3. *Continue* holding the `Ctrl` key, then press the **`E`** key which will execute the highlighted text.

If you want to delete the code just executed, you should *Continue* holding the `Ctrl` key and then press the `Delete` key.

*I suppose it is possible that someone has created a tool to do that automatically.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know how to use ctrl/shift with a mouse to select code and feel that's kind of slow comparing with shortkeys/snippets. Are you aware of any shortkeys/snippets that can select code automatically?

Comment: @RLF, I will award your answer with an upvote for successful trolling (intentional or not, doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible.  See complete list of default out of the box shortcuts [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx).  You may be able to customize something from the tools --> options menu

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If shortkeys are not possible, are you aware of any snippets for this?

Comment: Not that I can think of